# Convertir columnas de una tabla en filas

Tags: sql, sql-server

En un sistema en el cual estoy trabajando actualmente, hay una tabla de esta forma

```
  Id_Sucursal   Id_Servicio F_Descarga  Id_Tecnico  Con_Costo_1 Id_Producto_1   Cantidad_1  Costo_1 Precio_1    Tipo_1  Oferta_1    Precio_Oferta_1 Cantidad_Oferta_1   Con_Costo_2 Id_Producto_2   Cantidad_2  Costo_2 Precio_2    Tipo_2  Oferta_2    Precio_Oferta_2 Cantidad_Oferta_2   Con_Costo_3 Id_Producto_3   Cantidad_3  Costo_3 Precio_3    Tipo_3  Oferta_3    Precio_Oferta_3 Cantidad_Oferta_3   Con_Costo_4 Id_Producto_4   Cantidad_4  Costo_4 Precio_4    Tipo_4  Oferta_4    Precio_Oferta_4 Cantidad_Oferta_4   Con_Costo_5 Id_Producto_5   Cantidad_5  Costo_5 Precio_5    Tipo_5  Oferta_5    Precio_Oferta_5 Cantidad_Oferta_5   Con_Costo_6 Id_Producto_6   Cantidad_6  Costo_6 Precio_6    Tipo_6  Oferta_6    Precio_Oferta_6 Cantidad_Oferta_6   Con_Costo_7 Id_Producto_7   Cantidad_7  Costo_7 Precio_7    Tipo_7  Oferta_7    Precio_Oferta_7 Cantidad_Oferta_7   Con_Costo_8 Id_Producto_8   Cantidad_8  Costo_8 Precio_8    Tipo_8  Oferta_8    Precio_Oferta_8 Cantidad_Oferta_8   Con_Costo_9 Id_Producto_9   Cantidad_9  Costo_9 Precio_9    Tipo_9  Oferta_9    Precio_Oferta_9 Cantidad_Oferta_9   Con_Costo_10    Id_Producto_10  Cantidad_10 Costo_10    Precio_10   Tipo_10 Oferta_10   Precio_Oferta_10    Cantidad_Oferta_10  Con_Costo_11    Id_Producto_11  Cantidad_11 Costo_11    Precio_11   Tipo_11 Oferta_11   Precio_Oferta_11    Cantidad_Oferta_11  Con_Costo_12    Id_Producto_12  Cantidad_12 Costo_12    Precio_12   Tipo_12 Oferta_12   Precio_Oferta_12    Cantidad_Oferta_12  Con_Costo_13    Id_Producto_13  Cantidad_13 Costo_13    Precio_13   Tipo_13 Oferta_13   Precio_Oferta_13    Cantidad_Oferta_13  Con_Costo_14    Id_Producto_14  Cantidad_14 Costo_14    Precio_14   Tipo_14 Oferta_14   Precio_Oferta_14    Cantidad_Oferta_14  Con_Costo_15    Id_Producto_15  Cantidad_15 Costo_15    Precio_15   Tipo_15 Oferta_15   Precio_Oferta_15    Cantidad_Oferta_15  F_Entrada   Usr_Entrada F_Salida    Usr_Salida  F_Ult_Mod   Usr_Ult_Mod Estatus
CORDOBA 0000000001006   2013-03-23 14:56:10.107         1084    1   200.00  401.36  P   N   0.00    0.00        982 1   800.00  1800.32 P   N   0.00    0.00        933 2   87.49   700.26  P   N   0.00    0.00        968 1   219.68  520.00  P   N   0.00    0.00        1083    1   174.59  300.02  P   N   0.00    0.00        954 1   200.00  350.32  P   N   0.00    0.00        1010    5   88.00   1760.90 P   N   0.00    0.00        1222    1   472.00  865.08  P   N   0.00    0.00            0   0.00    0.00    0   0   0.00    0.00            0   0.00    0.00    0   0   0.00    0.00            0   0.00    0.00    0   0   0.00    0.00            0   0.00    0.00    0   0   0.00    0.00            0   0.00    0.00    0   0   0.00    0.00            0   0.00    0.00    0   0   0.00    0.00            0   0.00    0.00    0   0   0.00    0.00    2013-03-23 14:56:10.107 TCAMANDIR   1900-01-01 00:00:00.000     2013-03-23 14:56:10.107 TCAMANDIR   A
CORDOBA 0000000002777   2013-07-31 11:10:41.543         960 1   152.00  300.01  P   N   0.00    0.00        1083    1   174.59  300.02  P   N   0.00    0.00        1084    1   200.00  401.36  P   N   0.00    0.00        982 1   800.00  1800.32 P   N   0.00    0.00        1222    1   472.00  865.08  P   N   0.00    0.00        1010    3   87.49   1050.00 P   N   0.00    0.00        979 1   630.00  1205.82 P   N   0.00    0.00        968 1   258.05  590.00  P   N   0.00    0.00            0   0.00    0.00    0   0   0.00    0.00            0   0.00    0.00    0   0   0.00    0.00            0   0.00    0.00    0   0   0.00    0.00            0   0.00    0.00    0   0   0.00    0.00            0   0.00    0.00    0   0   0.00    0.00            0   0.00    0.00    0   0   0.00    0.00            0   0.00    0.00    0   0   0.00    0.00    2013-07-31 11:10:41.543 TCACBACAPTURA   1900-01-01 00:00:00.000     2013-07-31 11:10:41.543 TCACBACAPTURA   A
CORDOBA 0000000009229   2014-08-12 13:15:34.827         1089    1   1125.80 2300.00 P   N   0.00    0.00        1110    4   71.92   1400.00 P   N   0.00    0.00        1112    1   657.34  1150.00 P   N   0.00    0.00        1245    1   68.91   360.00  P   N   0.00    0.00        876 1   76.18   360.00  P   N   0.00    0.00        1091    1   102.62  490.00  P   N   0.00    0.00        890 1   260.13  490.01  P   N   0.00    0.00        1091    1   102.62  490.00  P   N   0.00    0.00            0   0.00    0.00    0   0   0.00    0.00            0   0.00    0.00    0   0   0.00    0.00            0   0.00    0.00    0   0   0.00    0.00            0   0.00    0.00    0   0   0.00    0.00            0   0.00    0.00    0   0   0.00    0.00            0   0.00    0.00    0   0   0.00    0.00            0   0.00    0.00    0   0   0.00    0.00    2014-08-12 13:15:34.827 COMPRAS 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000     2014-08-12 13:15:34.827 COMPRAS A
CORDOBA 0000000002108   2013-06-29 11:29:05.357         1222    1   472.00  865.08  P   N   0.00    0.00        968 1   258.05  590.00  P   N   0.00    0.00        1084    1   200.00  401.36  P   N   0.00    0.00        960 1   152.00  300.01  P   N   0.00    0.00        1083    1   174.59  300.02  P   N   0.00    0.00        982 1   800.00  1800.32 P   N   0.00    0.00        1010    4   87.49   1400.00 P   N   0.00    0.00        1024    2   308.24  1019.98 P   N   0.00    0.00            0   0.00    0.00    0   0   0.00    0.00            0   0.00    0.00    0   0   0.00    0.00            0   0.00    0.00    0   0   0.00    0.00            0   0.00    0.00    0   0   0.00    0.00            0   0.00    0.00    0   0   0.00    0.00            0   0.00    0.00    0   0   0.00    0.00            0   0.00    0.00    0   0   0.00    0.00    2013-06-29 11:29:05.357 TCACBACAPTURA   1900-01-01 00:00:00.000     2013-06-29 11:29:05.357 TCACBACAPTURA   A
```

Quiero cambiar la forma de la tabla, de una forma que la info ahí guardada sí funcione, a algo parecido a esto:

```
Id_Sucursal Id_Servicio F_Descarga          Id_Tecnico  Con_Costo_1 Id_Producto_1   Cantidad_1  Costo_1 Precio_1    Tipo_1  Oferta_1    Precio_Oferta_1 Cantidad_Oferta_1
CORDOBA         34991   18/11/2017 13:37                                    2856            2    20.58    59.7          P       N           0               0
CORDOBA         34991   18/11/2017 13:37                                    2861            4     2.59    15.04         P       N           0               0
CORDOBA         34991   18/11/2017 13:37                                    2867            4     3.88    22.52         P       N           0               0
```

¿Es posible en sql server?

Leí sobre pivot y unpivot, pero no termino de entender cómo funciona, y por lo tanto cómo lo implementaría en este caso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma de hacerlo es crear una nueva tabla con la estructura deseada y rellenarla a partir de los datos de la tabla original haciendo insert con select para cada conjunto de datos diferentes que quieres convertir en tuplas o filas en la nueva tabla.

Pongo un ejemplo en el que la tabla original tiene dos conjuntos de datos (_1 y _2 por tupla) y en la tabla nueva cada uno a a constituir una tupla.

**Schema (PostgreSQL v10.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  Id_Sucursal VARCHAR(50),
  Id_Servicio VARCHAR(50),
  Id_Tecnico VARCHAR(50),
  Con_Costo_1 VARCHAR(50),
  Id_Producto_1 INT,
  Cantidad_1 INT,
  Costo_1 DECIMAL,
  Precio_1 DECIMAL,
  Tipo_1 VARCHAR(2),
  Oferta_1 VARCHAR(2),
  Precio_Oferta_1 DECIMAL,
  Cantidad_Oferta_1 INT,
  Con_Costo_2 VARCHAR(50),
  Id_Producto_2 INT,
  Cantidad_2 INT,
  Costo_2 DECIMAL,
  Precio_2 DECIMAL,
  Tipo_2 VARCHAR(2),
  Oferta_2 VARCHAR(2),
  Precio_Oferta_2 DECIMAL,
  Cantidad_Oferta_2 INT
);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (
'CORDOBA', '0000000001006', '', 
'', 2856, 2, 20.58, 59.7, 'P','N', 0,0, 
'', 2857, 3, 40.53, 79.7, 'P','N', 0,0
);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (
  'CORDOBA', '0000000001007','',
  '', 2858, 2, 10.58, 39.7, 'P','N', 0,0,
  '', 2859, 3, 20.53, 89.7, 'P','N', 0,0
);

CREATE TABLE test2 (
  Id_Sucursal VARCHAR(50),
  Id_Servicio VARCHAR(50),
  Id_Tecnico VARCHAR(50),
  Con_Costo_1 VARCHAR(50),
  Id_Producto_1 INT,
  Cantidad_1 INT,
  Costo_1 DECIMAL,
  Precio_1 DECIMAL,
  Tipo_1 VARCHAR(2),
  Oferta_1 VARCHAR(2),
  Precio_Oferta_1 DECIMAL,
  Cantidad_Oferta_1 INT
);

INSERT INTO test2
(SELECT Id_Sucursal, Id_Servicio, Id_Tecnico,
  Con_Costo_1, Id_Producto_1, Cantidad_1, Costo_1, Precio_1,
  Tipo_1, Oferta_1, Precio_Oferta_1, Cantidad_Oferta_1
FROM test) ;
INSERT INTO test2
(SELECT Id_Sucursal, Id_Servicio, Id_Tecnico,
  Con_Costo_2, Id_Producto_2, Cantidad_2, Costo_2, Precio_2,
  Tipo_2, Oferta_2, Precio_Oferta_2, Cantidad_Oferta_2
FROM test);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * FROM test;

| id_sucursal | id_servicio   | id_tecnico | con_costo_1 | id_producto_1 | cantidad_1 | costo_1 | precio_1 | tipo_1 | oferta_1 | precio_oferta_1 | cantidad_oferta_1 | con_costo_2 | id_producto_2 | cantidad_2 | costo_2 | precio_2 | tipo_2 | oferta_2 | precio_oferta_2 | cantidad_oferta_2 |

| ----------- | ------------- | ---------- | ----------- | ------------- | ---------- | ------- | -------- | ------ | -------- | --------------- | ----------------- | ----------- | ------------- | ---------- | ------- | -------- | ------ | -------- | --------------- | ----------------- |

| CORDOBA     | 0000000001006 |            |             | 2856          | 2          | 20.58   | 59.7     | P      | N        | 0               | 0                 |             | 2857          | 3          | 40.53   | 79.7     | P      | N        | 0               | 0                 |
| CORDOBA     | 0000000001007 |            |             | 2858          | 2          | 10.58   | 39.7     | P      | N        | 0               | 0                 |             | 2859          | 3          | 20.53   | 89.7     | P      | N        | 0               | 0                 |
```

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT * FROM test2 ORDER BY id_servicio;

| id_sucursal | id_servicio   | id_tecnico | con_costo_1 | id_producto_1 | cantidad_1 | costo_1 | precio_1 | tipo_1 | oferta_1 | precio_oferta_1 | cantidad_oferta_1 |

| ----------- | ------------- | ---------- | ----------- | ------------- | ---------- | ------- | -------- | ------ | -------- | --------------- | ----------------- |

| CORDOBA     | 0000000001006 |            |             | 2856          | 2          | 20.58   | 59.7     | P      | N        | 0               | 0                 |
| CORDOBA     | 0000000001006 |            |             | 2857          | 3          | 40.53   | 79.7     | P      | N        | 0               | 0                 |
| CORDOBA     | 0000000001007 |            |             | 2858          | 2          | 10.58   | 39.7     | P      | N        | 0               | 0                 |
| CORDOBA     | 0000000001007 |            |             | 2859          | 3          | 20.53   | 89.7     | P      | N        | 0               | 0                 |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!! :-)